# Next Prev showing little error Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem in my next and prev.

When I click on previous button, the first time nothing happens. I tried `alert(url(' + images[i++] + '));`

but it was empty first time. But Second time when I press, it works fine. same happening with the next button. i don't know what causing this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**html:**

```
<div id="containerBox1">
  <ul class="buttons" style="margin-top: 182px;">
      <li><a class="triggerright masterTooltip" id="right1" title="Next">Right</a></li>
      <li><a class="triggerleft masterTooltip" id="left1" title="Previous">Left</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
<script>
    var getUrl = 'images/Logos/facebook.png';
    var refreshInterval;
    var i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ['images/Logos/facebook.png', 'images/Logos/gmail.png', 'images/Logos/twitter.png'];

    function changeBackground() {
      getUrl = images[i];
      $('#containerBox1').css('background-image', function() {
          if (i >= images.length) {
              getUrl = 'images/Logos/facebook.png';
              i = 0;
          }
          return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';
      });
    }

    // Set an interval to continue
    //refreshInterval = setInterval(changeBackground, 8000);

    $("#left1").click(function() {

      // Clear interval
      //clearInterval(refreshInterval);
      $('#containerBox1').css('background-image', function() {
          if (i <= 0) {
              i = images.length;
          }
          return 'url(' + images[--i] + ')';
      });
    });

    $("#right1").click(function() {
      // Clear interval
      //clearInterval(refreshInterval);

      $('#containerBox1').css('background-image', function() {
          if (i >= images.length) {
              i = 0;
          }
          return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';
      });

      // Set interval again
      //setInterval(changeBackground, 8000);
    });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: @user3351494 where should i use this? in the previous click part?

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4mjoesw/). Your `prev` works "as is" without errors, `next` is modified to `++i`.

Comment: @Regent if you click on next button 068 pic show which is work and not 067.png.

Comment: Because default value of `i` is "1". If you change it to "0", then at first `next` click "067.png" will be shown.

Comment: thanku so much. it worked out perfectly.